# How to get the id of a programmatically generated object?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a WebApp (Java code) and have to use AJAX to avoid too many reloads after users actions.
But I'm a beginner with JavaScript.
This WebApp is a social network where users may create posts, reply to posts or like posts.

For a given user's page, I have to show all the posts written on it.
I use a loop to write posts on the user's page, and, for each post, two pictures: like/dislike.
Users may vote for a post by clicking on one of these pictures.
Once a picture is clicked, a JavaScript function will work in background to increment a counter of likes/dislikes and refresh data on the page.

I can't use `document.getElementById()` to get the specific `id` of the liked/disliked post because `id` or `name` elements have to be unique on a page.

What should I do to get the `id` of the post by clicking on the like/dislike picture near a given post ?

Here is the code I use to loop over the list of posts to show :

```
<c:forEach var="post" items="${requestScope['postVotes']}">
 <ul>
 <c:if test="${post.key.responseLevelMessage == 0}">
   <hr>
   <li><font size="2"> Le ${post.key.messageDate} par 
   <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/CentralStation?section=votePage&CurrentContext=${post.key.messageId}">${post.key.messageSender}</a>
   <br>
   <br> ${post.key.messageTitle}<br>
  ${post.key.messageContent}<br>
   </font>
 </c:if>
 <c:if test="${post.key.responseLevelMessage > 0}">
   <li><font size="1"> 
   <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/CentralStation?section=votePage&CurrentContext=${post.key.messageId}">${post.key.messageSender}</a><br>
   <br> ${post.key.messageContent}<br>
   </font>
 </c:if>

 <c:choose>
   //1st case : connected user already voted "like"
  <c:when test="${post.value == 1}">
    <input type="image" src="img/heart-clear.png" value="${post.key.messageId}" onclick="alertForKeyValue();">
    <input type="image" src="img/heart-dislike.png" value="${post.key.messageId}" onclick="alertForKeyValue();">
  </c:when>
   //2nd case : connected user did not vote yet
  <c:when test="${post.value == 0}">
    <input type="image" src="img/heart-like.png" value="${post.key.messageId}" onclick="alertForKeyValue();">
    <input type="image" src="img/heart-dislike.png" value="${post.key.messageId}" onclick="alertForKeyValue();">
  </c:when>
   //3rd case : connected user already voted "dislike"
  <c:when test="${post.value == -1}">
    <input type="image" src="img/heart-like.png" value="${post.key.messageId}" onclick="alertForKeyValue();">
    <input type="image" src="img/heart-clear.png" value="${post.key.messageId}" onclick="alertForKeyValue();">
  </c:when>
 </c:choose>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </c:forEach>
```

${post.key.messageId} is the JSTL expression containing the post ID.

As you can see, the post id value is stocked near each written button. I tried to use ID/NAME attributes, giving them the post ID value, but the JS function was always returning me a "undefined" value.

Here is a poor print screen of the page's look. Each post has a pair of buttons like/dislike :*

[image: Each post has a pair of buttons for voting : like / dislike]

Comment: It would be a **lot** easier for people to help you if you showed us the DOM structure in question. Are the Like/Dislike buttons *near* the post, or within a container that also contains that post (and not other posts)? Your starting point here will be `this` within the `click` callback.

Comment: You don't need to have `id` or `name` - for example `<a href="#" onclick="like([id-of-your-post])">Like</a>` can be used, with `like` being a function you create to handle sending the data to DB

Comment: @canisminor Yes, I keep the good idea of creating like() and dislike() functions called regarding at the clicked picture.

But when I write the code like this :

<input type="image" src="img/heart-plus.png"      value="${post.key.messageId}" onclick="like(${post.key.messageId});">

the result I got is "undefined", not the value contained in the JSTL expression.

Comment: @Lovegiver with the markup provided, in `alertForKeyValue` do `alert(this.value)` - if JSTL generated correct markup (so, within your `value` field there's something, `this.value` will contain the value of it

Comment: It worked @canisminor !!
2 days lost for such a poor thing...

Thanx a lot, you did it :)

Answer (score 4):

Often people will use a `data` attribute to keep track of stuff like this in the markup. The key is to put these data attributes in the markup with server side code. Example:

**Markup:**

```
<article class="post" data-post-id="1">
    <button class="like-button" data-post-id="1">Like</button>
</article>
```

**JS (using jQuery):**

```
$('.like-button').on('click', function(){
    var postId = $(this).data('post-id');
    // Do some stuff with the postId
});
```

Comment: thanx for your suggestion.

I have 2 questions about Markup one as I do not know jQuery at all :

1) Considering the code extract I gave, where should I use your <article class="post" ...> ? Should it wrap my whole script or only <input type="image"... > markups ? I tried it surrounding the whole script, but my image-buttons aren't clickable anymore.
2) I'm using <input type="image"...>, not <button...>. Does your solution work only for classic button ?

Comment: A third question just came to me : are Markup and JS alternatives solutions or a single one ?

Comment: Hi there, I used `<article>` and `<button>` HTML elements but you could use any elements, including an `<img>`. Have a look at the Docs for jQuery's [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function and the [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function. Again, the important part is to associate the inputs (the like/dislike buttons) with the thing they are manipulating, in this case by using data attributes.

Comment: By markup I just mean HTML, sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: 'data' function seems very powerful !

Thanx for making me discover such a tool.

Markup/HTML was clear, what I don't understand is the relation between <article> and <button> : why the button markup is inside the article one ?

Comment: Concerning the <article> markup, is this just a way for jQuery to specify a point in the document so that everything under this point is in the scope if the jQuery action ?

For example :
<div>A div</div>
<button>Get "blah" from the div</button>
...

and then :

  switch ( $( "button" ).index( this ) ) {
    case 0 :
      value = $( "div" ).data( "blah" );
      break;

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to @canisminor the problem was solved by adding the "this.value" argument to the calling function :

```
<input type="image" src="img/heart-remove.png"
    value="${post.key.messageId}"
    onclick="dislike(this.value);">
```

The Like() and Dislike() functions (also suggested by CanisMinor) receive the correct argument (the post ID) and now have datas to work with.

I also wanna thanx @stafree for his very interesting introduction to jQuery powerful function named "Data".
I actually do not know anything about jQuery (just like JS in fact...), but what I've red on the jQuery website about the Data function is mostly interesting.

Thanx to all of you.

Comment: While `.data()` is indeed jQuery function, you could have used any attribute (for example, `rel` attribute was pretty popular for that purposes before HTML5). Have a look here: https://www.abeautifulsite.net/working-with-html5-data-attributes - author provides usage of `data` without jQuery. Also, your `dislike` function - you don't need to pass `this.value` to it. You can as well do `onclick="dislike()"` and within your `dislike` function body access the value via `this.value`. In this instance `this` represents DOM element on which JS function is called upon

Comment: Hi @canisminor 

as you suggested, I've tried calling like()/dislike functions without passing any argument in it, but I experienced the same problem as before : "Undefined"

`<c:when test="${post.value == 1}">
  <input type="image" src="img/up.png" value="${post.key.messageId}" onclick="like();">
 [...]
 </c:when>`

The JS script to test :
`function like(){
 alert("Like " + this.value);
}`

I dunno why the function doesn't catch the actual value, but I'm sure my bad understanding of JS may explains many things.

Comment: not your fault - I was mis-remembering some things as well. I've created a jsbin for you here - http://jsbin.com/pugojonaju/. The issue is with `this` and it being passed to functions body - it's not. The function actually fires with `this` being `window`, so that's where `undefined` comes from. You actually need to pass `this` as element to the function (to tell what node the function operates). Apologies!

Answer (score -3):

Use `.parentElement()`, `.getElementId()`, `.nextSibling()` etc. to select nearby elements.

More info on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp).